# convert gene name to uniprot id with python

Tags: python

I have a list of gene names. Is there any python script to convert them to uniprot ID? I also tried using mygene library, but I couldn't get results as most of the genes were missing due to conversion.

Comment: [mre] read this

Answer (score 3):

You can now use [the Unipressed package](https://github.com/multimeric/Unipressed#id-mapping) by Michael Milton ([@multimeric](https://twitter.com/multimeric)) to do ID mapping in Python, see [the announcement](https://twitter.com/multimeric/status/1563503719508893697).

An example with three human genes giving the Uniprot identifiers / accession codes:

```py
from unipressed import IdMappingClient
import time
request = IdMappingClient.submit(
    source="GeneCards", dest="UniProtKB", ids={"POTEB3", "SYCE3", "CLRN2"}
)
time.sleep(1.0)
list(request.each_result())
```

Result is:

```
[{'from': 'POTEB3', 'to': 'A0JP26'},
 {'from': 'CLRN2', 'to': 'A0PK11'},
 {'from': 'SYCE3', 'to': 'A1L190'}]
```

It is basically the reverse of the example currently in [the Unipressed documentation for ID mapping](https://multimeric.github.io/Unipressed/#id-mapping). the example there is UniProtKB Accession to gene name for three human genes.

For working out what to use for the source and destination databases, you can try a few examples by hand using the [UniProt Retrieve/ID mapping webpage](https://www.uniprot.org/id-mapping). When you get a result that works, there is an 'API REQUEST' tab on the result page that shows you the API request curl code. You can use what it shows there to get the `FROM` and `TO` to use as the `source` and `dest` settings in your modified verson of the code.

See more examples of using Unipressed to access Uniprot's new REST API [here in my reply to Biostar's post 'Accessing UNIPROT using REST API'](https://www.biostars.org/p/286919/#9537049).
At [the bottom here](https://www.biostars.org/p/9560315/#9560336) I include converting the 'from - to' results list into a Pandas dataframe.